# AutoCompleteTextView loses focus

Tags: android

I have `ListView` which I populate with **AutoCompleteTextView** and **EditText**. User can add programatically new rows and edit them. However, when I add two or more rows I cannot type inside second/third and so on **AutoCompleteTextView** - when I touch the **TextView** the keyboard appears but I can't type anything because it loses focus on **AutoCompleteTextView**. Here is my adapter getView and xml with design of row.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if(convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.add_meal_activity_list_view_row, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.productNameTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) convertView.
                        findViewById(R.id.mealPartAutoCompleteTextView);
                holder.foodQuantityEditText = (EditText) convertView.
                        findViewById(R.id.mealQuantityEditText);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.foodQuantityEditText
                .setText(Utilities.trimDecimalsToString(_mealParts.get(position).foodQuantity));
            holder.foodQuantityEditText.addTextChangedListener(new FoodQuantityTextWatcher(position, holder.foodQuantityEditText));

            //TODO here fetch real product names from web API
            //TODO on item selected - pass to mealPart proudctId of chosen product
            ArrayAdapter<String> productNamesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(_context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, DATA);
            holder.productNameTextView.setAdapter(productNamesAdapter);
            holder.productNameTextView.addTextChangedListener(new ProductNameTextWatcher(position,holder.productNameTextView));

            return convertView;
        }
```

Here is row definition.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/mealPartAutoCompleteTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:completionThreshold="2"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        style="@style/ListTextView" />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/mealQuantityEditText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        style="@style/ListTextView"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is activity in which rows of a list are populated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    style="@style/ListViewStyle"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
    android:focusable="true">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/mealNameTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/mealNameTextViewHint"
        style="@style/TitleTextViewStyle" />

   <ListView android:id="@+id/mealPartsListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/okMealButton"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_accept"
                android:contentDescription="@string/addMealPartButtonContentDescription"
                android:onClick="onOkMealClick"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                android:padding="5dp">
        </ImageButton>
        <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/addMealPartButton"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_new"
                android:contentDescription="@string/addMealPartButtonContentDescription"
                android:onClick="onAddMealPartButtonClick"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground">
        </ImageButton>
        <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/addFavouriteMeal"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_favorite"
                android:contentDescription="@string/addMealPartButtonContentDescription"
                android:onClick="onAddMealPartButtonClick"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground">
        </ImageButton>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**UPDATE**

I have looked at LogCat and when I click on AutoComplete that I can't get focus on it logs somethins like this:

01-07 12:35:08.685: E/SpannableStringBuilder(29361): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

Comment: try it by setting listview focusable state to false

Comment: didin't help, still the same problem

Comment: for AutoCompleteTextView and editext set focusable to false and remove  android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true" from linear layout in the same layout

Comment: well now I can't get focus on any of them, let alone type in them. Keyboard doesnt appear as well

Comment: @MichaelCwienczek  From code will you add or from Layout. I think you just dynamically call Adapter and it will be added...... right?

Comment: From code will I add what? I am adding rows inside button onClick event. Then user can fill in the row.

Comment: @VsMaX did you get the solution for this..

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a *Keyboard* error for your particular device. See [Android - SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670374/android-span-exclusive-exclusive-spans-cannot-have-a-zero-length)

Have you tried testing on the emulator or on other devices?

Additionally, some report that changing the `inputType` setting has fixed the issue. Try some different options. Since the options for your `AutoCompleteTextView` are downloaded, you may try setting this field to `none`:

```
android:inputType="none"
```

This is used to answer [Android Google Analytics SDK show "SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16686710/android-google-analytics-sdk-show-span-exclusive-exclusive-spans-cannot-have-a)

Comment: I have tried on both Galaxy S3 and Galaxy Note 2 and problem still persists, both on Swiftkey keyboard and Samsung keyboard. The problem doesn't persist on emulators though. I have seen the topic you linked, unfortunately this is theoretical dispute over what SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE means and doesnt help much.

Comment: @MichaelCwienczek have you tried the second part of my answer - have you changed the `inputType`?

Comment: I have just tested it, the problem still exists. I am switching to ScrollView and maybe that will help solve problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can get edittext focus using this-

```
holder.foodQuantityEditText = (EditText) convertView.                 findViewById(R.id.mealQuantityEditText);

holder.foodQuantityEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(final View v, boolean hasFocus) 
            {
                v.post(new Runnable() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run() 
                    {
                        if (!v.hasFocus()) {
                            v.requestFocus();
                            v.requestFocusFromTouch();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like

```
EditText etselect;
etselect.requestFocus(); // This will provide focus on that.
```

Hope it helps you some how.!

Comment: where I should do that? In on click event? Besides, this seems to be only temporary fix, not real solution.

Comment: No problem .. i will check that again. Will get back to U

Answer (score -1):

AutoCompleteTextView will not work with ListView.

When the keyboard is shown, the layout will be either resized or pan(scroll) to fit the keyboard and your AutoCompleteTextView. Due to this the ListView has to refresh itself which make the AutoCompleteTextView to lose focus and the dropdown will never be shown.

I would suggest you to use a ScrollView instead.

I am not sure, but I think if your adapter uses a stable item id then ListView will reuse the same view for particular item and may be AutoCompleteTextView will not lose the focus.